# Why image not showing while download html to pdf using JavaScript (kendo)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Does anyone have an idea why the image does not come along with HTML in pdf?**

in the below image you can see the image is missing in pdf and I have added that image in the HTML part.so I want to download the image also in pdf.

[image: HTML to PDF Example]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

        <div class="container row m-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 pl-3">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm export-pdf k-button" onclick="getPDF('.pdf-page')">Download Invoice</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pdf-page A4 p-3">
        <div style="padding:10px;border:1px solid white;">
            <div class="container-fluid p-0 invoice-page border border-dark">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        
                                <div class="invoice-header pt-3 p-2 b-b">
                                    <div class="ribbon">
                                        <h6>PAID</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container-fluid row" style="align-items: center;">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <img src="https://championsemi.com/assets/img/bg1.jpg" width="100%">
                                            <kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" margin="2cm">
                                          <img src="{{url + '.jpg'}}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="" />
                                        </kendo-pdf-export>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <h6 class="font-weight-bold pb-1">PCB Magic</h6>
                                            <p>
                                                419-A Logix Technova
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                Sector 132, NOIDA 
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                (UP)201304, INDIA
                                            </p>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 " style="align-self: flex-end;">
                                            <h4 class="text-right text-capitalize">TAX INVOICE</h4>
                                            <p class="text-center">Orignal Invioce</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="from-to b-b bg-light">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 b-r ">
                                            <p class="p-2 font-weight-bold">Bill To</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <p class="p-2 font-weight-bold">Ship To</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
      function getPDF(selector) {
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(selector)).then(function(group){
          kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Invoice.pdf");
        });
      }
      

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add the logo in the given HTML and download the same in pdf.
everything is working perfectly apart from the image.

Comment: Have you looks at the console? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images located on a different domain than the page itself, you are getting into cross-origin violation issue, which doesn't allow download images from different domains.

https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/0oe5vt2s/

produces error:

> Access to image at 'https://championsemi.com/assets/img/bg1.jpg' from
> origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource

But as you can see the image that was embedded into the page downloaded and included into pdf just fine.

Comment: What is the solution? Encode the external image URL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what backend you are using in your project, but you should return the MemoryStream (byte[]) array for the image tag and same apply it into SCR of the Image Tag, instead of the path in the Image tag.